# Python - Replacing column by indexing removes imaginary components

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I am trying to replace an array of 0's column by column like this

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((2,10))
b = np.linspace(1,10,10) 
a[1,:] = b
```

which gives the correct output

```
a = [[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
     [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]]
b = [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
```

However, the data I am trying to insert is complex, for some reason this form of indexing removes the imaginary part of the data. For example

```
a = np.zeros((2,10))
b = np.linspace(1,10,10) * 1j #now b is imaginary
a[1,:] = b
```

returns the following

```
a = [[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
     [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
b = [0. +1.j 0. +2.j 0. +3.j 0. +4.j 0. +5.j 0. +6.j 0. +7.j 0. +8.j 0. +9.j
     0.+10.j]
```

which is obviously incorrect. Is there a way to avoid this and keep the data complex? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have just realised this is due to the zero matrix being a different type of data and is fixed by using

```
a = np.zeros((2,2),dtype = np.complex)
```

for reference if anyone else has the same problem